# Replace a specific number in file on ssh

Tags: shell, ssh

Need to replace a line in a specific file on multiple hosts using `pssh`:

The file is located at `a/b/c.txt` and contians

```
myPackage /version/21 install
```

I need to replace this line with

```
myPackage /version/22 install
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sed` the stream editor. `-i` will replace the contents back to the file:

```
$ cat test.txt
blah blah blah blah blah myPackage /version/21 install blah blah blah
blah blah myPackage /version/21 install
myPackage /version/21 install blah blah
myPackage /version/21 install

$ sed -i "s/21 install/22 install/" test.txt

$ cat test.txt
blah blah blah blah blah myPackage /version/22 install blah blah blah
blah blah myPackage /version/22 install
myPackage /version/22 install blah blah
myPackage /version/22 install
```

Comment: and since he want to use it with pssh: `parallel-ssh -h hostslist 'sed -i "s/21 install/22 install/" a/b/c.txt'`

Answer (score -1):

If the file is identical on all machines, you could just push the corrected copy of the file.

Something like:

```
for h in $(<hosts); do
  scp c-updated.txt $h:a/b/c.txt
done
```